# ngRepeat doesn't fully reload DOM on simple array

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using simple array of numbers like below with `ng-repeat`:

```
n = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

The issue is, when I change this array for eg:

```
n=[1,2,3]
```

It doesn't fully reload the DOM but instead it just remove the last 3 `div` elements related to array `4, 5, 6`. Is there any way to force the `ng-repeat` to reload DOM everytime I change the array.

Comment: Why do you want to reload the dom?

Comment: That is actually a feature, not a bug.

Comment: Thats why AngularJS is such cool, data-binding on MV*. But, what exactly is your problem with this behavior?

Comment: Actually I am using different layout everytime I change the array. Otherwise ngRepeat doesn't update `div` element related to first 3 array values.

Comment: @codelearner, I suggest you add more details about your change of layout objective

Answer (score 1):

Have you try it change the array into an $apply call?, something like:

```
$scope.$apply(function() {
    n = [1, 2, 3];
});
```

Comment: This also doesn't work because according to ngRepeat documentation - **Should you reload your data later, ngRepeat will not have to rebuild the DOM elements for items it has already rendered, even if the JavaScript objects in the collection have been substituted for new ones.**

Comment: This article could help you then:  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2443-rendering-dom-elements-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm

Comment: @didando8a Thanks for the link. But I am using simple array of numbers not objects.